# Make Treesitter interpret a Heading text inside a List item as a normal Heading title

Tags: markdown, neovim, treesitter

I want to make Neovim Treesitter to interpret the following markdown list item line as a title line. Is this possible?

```
- ## Heading title in a List item
```

I need this because there is another plugin called [telescope-heading.nvim](https://github.com/crispgm/telescope-heading.nvim) that allows me to navigate headings. All my heading titles are embedded inside list items because I keep all these markdown files as [Logseq](https://logseq.com) documents. And Logseq by default enforces me to structure the markdown text as list items to treat all the text as a tree outline.

Comment: @Chris apparently it is: https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=-%20%23%23%20Heading

Comment: @mb21, [I stand corrected](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#example-300)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem through some other way. Instead of making Treesitter interpret "List items" as "Markdown headings", I edited the code of [crispgm/telescope-heading.nvim](https://github.com/crispgm/telescope-heading.nvim) where the plugin matches the headings.

Edit `~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/telescope-heading.nvim/lua/telescope/_extensions/heading/format/markdown.lua`

Add the following lines to "matches" array:

```
    local matches = {
        '- ',
        '- # ',
        '- ## ',
        '- ### ',
        '# ',
        ...
    }
```